# Python OGR: Finding bad spot in source code for code displacement

Tags: python, gdal, ogr

I've tried to adapt a python ogr script which displaces points too near to each other (originally from http://wiki.gis-lab.info/w/Displacement_of_points_with_same_coordinates,_ShiftPoints/OGR for python2) to Python3. I've also changed the GDAL driver from Shapefile to GeoJSON:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import math
from itertools import cycle
from optparse import OptionParser

try:
  from osgeo import ogr
except ImportError:
  import ogr

driverName = "GeoJSON"

class progressBar( object ):
  '''Class to display progress bar
  '''
  def __init__( self, maximum, barLength ):
    '''Init progressbar instance.

    @param maximum    maximum progress value
    @param barLength  length of the bar in characters
    '''
    self.maxValue = maximum
    self.barLength = barLength
    self.spin = cycle(r'-\|/').__next__
    self.lastLength = 0
    self.tmpl = '%-' + str( barLength ) + 's ] %c %5.1f%%'
    sys.stdout.write( '[ ' )
    sys.stdout.flush()

  def update( self, value ):
    '''Update progressbar.

    @param value    Input new progress value
    '''
    # Remove last state.
    sys.stdout.write( '\b' * self.lastLength )

    percent = value * 100.0 / self.maxValue
    # Generate new state
    width = int( percent / 100.0 * self.barLength )
    output = self.tmpl % ( '-' * width, self.spin(), percent )

    # Show the new state and store its length.
    sys.stdout.write( output )
    sys.stdout.flush()
    self.lastLength = len( output )

def __log( msg, abort = True, exitCode = 1 ):
  ''' display log message and abort execution

  @param msg       message to display
  @param abort     abort program execution or no. Default: True
  @param exitCode  exit code passed to sys.exit. Default: 1
  '''
  print(msg)
  if abort:
    sys.exit( exitCode )

def doDisplacement( src, dst, radius, rotate, logFile = None, logField = None ):
  ''' read source file and write displacement result to output file

  @param src     source shapefile
  @param dst     destination shapefile
  @param radius  displacement radius
  @param rotate  flag indicates rotate points or no
  '''

  # try to open source shapefile
  inShape = ogr.Open( src, False )
  if inShape is None:
    __log( "Unable to open source shapefile " + src )

  print(inShape)

  inLayer = inShape.GetLayer( 0 )

  print(inLayer)

  print(inLayer.GetGeomType())
  if inLayer.GetGeomType() not in [ ogr.wkbPoint, ogr.wkbPoint25D ]:
    __log( "Input layer should be point layer." )

  print(inLayer.GetFeatureCount())
  if inLayer.GetFeatureCount() == 0:
    __log( "There are no points in given shapefile." )

  drv = ogr.GetDriverByName( driverName )
  if drv is None:
    __log( "%s driver not available." % driverName )

  crs = inLayer.GetSpatialRef()

  # initialize output shapefile
  outShape = drv.CreateDataSource( dst )
  if outShape is None:
    __log( "Creation of output file %s failed." % dst )

  outLayer = outShape.CreateLayer( "point", crs, ogr.wkbPoint )
  if outLayer is None:
    __log( "Layer creation failed." )

  # create fields in output layer
  logIndex = 0
  featDef = inLayer.GetLayerDefn()
  for i in range( featDef.GetFieldCount() ):
    fieldDef = featDef.GetFieldDefn( i )

    if logField and logField.lower() == fieldDef.GetNameRHef().lower():
      logIndex = i

    if outLayer.CreateField ( fieldDef ) != 0:
      __log( "Creating %s field failed." % fieldDef.GetNameRef() )

  __log( "Search for overlapped features", abort = False )
  cn = 0
  pb = progressBar( inLayer.GetFeatureCount(), 65 )

  # find overlapped points
  displacement = dict()
  inLayer.ResetReading()
  inFeat = inLayer.GetNextFeature()
  while inFeat is not None:
    wkt = inFeat.GetGeometryRef().ExportToWkt()
    print(wkt)
    if wkt not in displacement:
      lst = [ inFeat.GetFID() ]
      displacement[ wkt ] = lst
    else:
      lst = displacement[ wkt ]
      j = [ inFeat.GetFID() ]
      j.extend( lst )
      displacement[ wkt ] = j
    cn += 1
    pb.update( cn )
    inFeat = inLayer.GetNextFeature()

  __log( "\nDisplace overlapped features", abort = False )
  cn = 0
  pb = progressBar( len( displacement ), 65 )

  lineIds = []
  lineValues = []
  lines = []
  pc = 0

  # move overlapped features and write them to output file
  for k, v in displacement.items():
    featNum = len( v )
    if featNum == 1:
      f = inLayer.GetFeature( v[ 0 ] )
      if outLayer.CreateFeature( f ) != 0:
        __log( "Failed to create feature in output shapefile." )
    else:
      pc += featNum

      fullPerimeter = 2 * math.pi
      angleStep = fullPerimeter / featNum
      if featNum == 2 and rotate:
        currentAngle = math.pi / 2
      else:
        currentAngle = 0
      for i in v:
        sinusCurrentAngle = math.sin( currentAngle )
        cosinusCurrentAngle = math.cos( currentAngle )
        dx = radius * sinusCurrentAngle
        dy = radius * cosinusCurrentAngle

        ft = inLayer.GetFeature( i )
        lineIds.append( str( ft.GetFID() ) )
        lineValues.append( ft.GetFieldAsString( logIndex ) )
        geom = ft.GetGeometryRef()
        x = geom.GetX()
        y = geom.GetY()
        pt = ogr.Geometry( ogr.wkbPoint )
        pt.SetPoint_2D( 0, x + dx, y + dy )

        f = ogr.Feature( outLayer.GetLayerDefn() )
        f.SetFrom( ft )
        f.SetGeometry( pt )
        if outLayer.CreateFeature( f ) != 0:
          __log( "Failed to create feature in output shapefile." )

        f.Destroy()
        currentAngle += angleStep

      # store logged info
      lines.append( ";".join( lineIds ) + "(" + ";".join( lineValues ) + ")\n" )
      lineIds = []
      lineValues = []

    cn += 1
    pb.update( cn )

  # cleanup
  print("\nPoints displaced: %d\n" % pc)
  inShape = None
  outShape = None

  # write log
  if logFile:
    fl = open( logFile, "w" )
    fl.writelines( lines )
    fl.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = OptionParser( usage = "displacement.py [OPTIONS] INPUT OUTPUT",
                         version = "%prog v0.1",
                         description = "Shift overlapped points so all of them becomes visible",
                         epilog = "Experimental version. Use at own risk." )

  parser.add_option( "-d", "--distance", action="store", dest="radius",
                     default=0.015, metavar="DISTANCE", type="float",
                     help="displacement distanse [default: %default]" )
  parser.add_option( "-r", "--rotate", action="store_true", dest="rotate",
                     default=False, help="place points horizontaly, if count = 2 [default: %default]" )
  parser.add_option( "-l", "--log", action="store", dest="logFile",
                     metavar="FILE",
                     help="log overlapped points to file [default: %default]. Makes no sense without '-f' option" )
  parser.add_option( "-f", "--field", action="store", dest="logField",
                     metavar="FIELD",
                     help="Shape field that will be logged to file. Makes no sense without '-l' option" )

  ( opts, args ) = parser.parse_args()

  if len( args ) != 2:
    parser.error( "incorrect number of arguments" )

  if opts.logFile and opts.logField:
    doDisplacement( args[ 0 ], args[ 1 ], opts.radius, opts.rotate, opts.logFile, opts.logField )
  else:
    doDisplacement( args[ 0 ], args[ 1 ], opts.radius, opts.rotate )
```

The script

1. finds displacement candidates by drawing a circle around each point
2. calculates the angle depending on the number of points to displace (e.g. 2 - 0 & 180)
3. moves the points

I'm using [this](https://pastebin.com/UWZWNJVw) input file. Executing `python displacement.py input.geojson output.geojson -d 100` should displace all points, but there are always 0 points displaced.

May you please help me finding out the cause?

Answer (score 0):

There is not bad spot in this code, it does exactly what it says it does.

It only displaces points which have the **exact** same coordinates. Your file has different coordinates. I tried it with a shapefile with the same coordinates, and it worked fine.

I guess you'll have to look for another solution.